# Proof check that $\int\limits_0^1\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\right)dx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_k}{k+1}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Prove the following:  If $\sum |a_{k}| < \infty$, prove that $\int\limits_{0}^{1} \left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k} \right)dx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{k}}{k+1}$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$: Fix $x \in [0,1]$. By the Weierstrass M-Test consider $\sum\limits M_{k}=|a_{k}| < \infty$; then it can be seen that $|a_{k}x^{k}| \leq M_{k}$,  $\forall x \in [0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore it follows that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} f_{k}(x)$. Since the sequence of functions converges uniformly, then $f_{k} \in \mathscr{R}[0,1], \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, $f(x) \in \mathscr{R}[0,1]$ as well with the following:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{k}(x)dx \\ \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \left[a_{k}x^{k} \right]dx \\ \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} \int_{0}^{1} \left[x^{k} \right]dx \\ \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_{k}}{k+1}
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{QED}$

I was wondering if my proof is correct; I was wanting to get some feedback! Prepping for a final this Thursday, and our professor kind of skimmed through this section quickly.

Comment: Looks mostly good. First, I'd explicitly define $f_k(x) = a_kx^k$; the way you defined $f_k$ isn't precise. Further, say explicitly that since $f_k$ are continuous then they are integrable, and that since the limit uniformly converges, then $f$ is continuous, and therefore integrable. And say that the integral and sum can be exchanged because the limit is uniform.

Comment: Thanks! Part of the reason I posted this question because I want to make sure that I'm being as specific, yet concise, as I can be. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: florence already said this, but just to be clear, the sentence "Since the sequence of functions converges uniformly, then $f_{k} \in \mathscr{R}[0,1], \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$" is false, or at least nonsense. you are not *concluding* that the $f_k$ are integrable *since* the convergence is uniform. you are concluding that **$f$** is integrable since the $f_k$ are continuous and the convergence is uniform.

Comment: The integration in the title shall run from $0$ to $1$ and also in the text ... :-)

Comment: Your proof is correct. Note that this is a special case of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_k$ as the dominating function.

Answer (score -1):

You are complicating too much.  We know that $ \sum a_{k}x^{k} $ is a power series and so we can integrate a power series term by term inside its interval of convergence. Since $ \sum \mid a_{k}\mid $ converges, 1 is in the interval of convergence. Then, continue...

I don't thing they want you to prove the cited theorem.

Comment: I agree with you, but for our exam they want us to use specific Theorems/Corollaries that were presented and proved. That's why I used them.

Comment: This is a classic theorem: Power series can be integrated term by term within their radius of convergence.